# Application isn't the active one, after an update with Sparkle

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, sparkle

I use Sparkle to provide updates for my application.

The process is a very simple and basic one : the updates for the application are zipped and an XML appcast provides Sparkle with the URL for the zip.

All work as expected, Sparkle advertises of an update, and once I click to install it, downloads, unpacks the archive, and asks to install and relaunch.

There is one problem : after relaunch the application isn't the active (foremost ?) one, that is : the application is (re)launched by the 'finish_installation' tool but stays at the bottom of the applications stack.

From how other apps updated by Sparkle behave, this isn't normal behavior and the application is correctly given focus by the system on normal, classic launches.

If it matters, I run Mac OS X 10.9.1 and Xcode 5.0.2, and the application is document-based.

I did notice a message in system log, saying the zip importer encountered an error (2) parsing the archive used for update, but I doubt this could be the root of the problem.

Does someone observed such a behavior already ? Even on a non-update configuration ?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't observed this behavior on my apps. But it should be easily fixable by adding `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];` in your app delegate's `awakeFromNib` or `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` methods.

If you only want the app to activate when it's being launched by 'finish_installation', maybe you could check the name of the parent process of your app ?

Comment: Yes I am aware of such workarounds, I was hoping and still hope for someone to put me on the right track for discovering the problem. Stealing the focus would be my last option here I think.